# Backups: Server vs. cPanel vs. Site ... how much is too much?

Tags: wordpress, server, backup, cpanel

My buddy has some sites that I help out on occasionally (site dev & maint).
He has a server hosting six domains. Each domain has it's own cPanel for managing a single WordPress site and associated email (*very* low volume).

His "backup policy" was to just err on the side of caution and enable everything.
Backups are happening at all three levels:

- Server backups
- Backups of each cPanel via WHM
- WordPress backups

It's coming back to bite him in the tail a bit because he pays per gig for the server-level backups.

The cpanel and wordpress backups seem wholly redundant in this current configuration/use case, but I'd like to get some input before actually putting any changes into effect.

I'm thinking to do daily backups at *either* the cPanel or WP level.
I'm leaning toward keeping the cPanel backups.
Would I be loosing anything by dropping WP backups?
Is there any reason I should keep both?

As for the server level backups ..  I'm thinking to take those every second or third day. If I'm taking daily site backups, is there any reason to go more often than three days?

Comment: I understand the impulse to close this question, but if this type of info were available when I searched, I would not have needed to post the question ... If there is some way to further edit/generalize this question to make it more useful, please make the changes or suggestions ... My intent is to frame the question in a way that could help others. too.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is the following:

1. Create an automated process to backup the WordPress database of each WordPress site at least daily
2. Create an automated process to backup the wp-content folder of each WordPress site at least weekly

**wp-content folder + database is a fully recoverable WordPress backup you do not need anything else.**

Configuration incompatibilities with the server may happen but most likely no big difficulties.

You can do server backups / CPanel backups in order to save your settings and/or mails but this is a different topic. I would not waste too much memory on this (however it depends on and this is opinionated).

(Btw. deleting old backups if recommendable if nothing occurs :-P)

Comment: Thanks-a-bunch for the helpful insight